# Unable to register services to the discovery server (EUREKA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

So when I run my service instance. It does not register itself to the discovery server. And there is no error, so I am not able to identify the problem here .

`application.properties` of my service looks like this and `application.properties` of the discovery server can be seen in the screenshot attached.

```
spring.application.name = service
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone =http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Eureka dashboard at localhost:8761 shows that there are no instances available for this service.

[image: This is the console]

Comment: in your application.properties, register-with-eureka is set as false. It should be true if you want to register your app.

Comment: @AddoZhang I changed it to true , Its still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this dependency in your `pom.xml`, that will give your service a reason to stay up:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Moreover, I think you should refactor your `application.properties` file for Eureka default zone part, like that:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Comment: In which application.properties file should I make the above changes ?

Comment: The `application.properties` of your service, which start with the line `spring.application.name = service`

Comment: It is deregistering itself immediately after registering .I am unable to understand the problem

Comment: If the app doesn't have a reason to stay up (ie listening for http requests as configured thru mentioned starter), eureka will deregister on shutdown. All of this is standard boot behavior